# Close dropdown on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
const dropdownBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-btn');
const dropdownLists = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-list');

dropdownBtns.forEach(function(dropdownBtn) {
  dropdownBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    dropdownLists.forEach(function(dropdownList) {
      if (dropdownList !== this.nextElementSibling) {
        dropdownList.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
    this.nextElementSibling.style.display = this.nextElementSibling.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
    
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 50px;
}

.dropdown-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown 1</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="item-1"> <label for="item-1">Item 1</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="item-2"> <label for="item-2">Item 2</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="item-3"> <label for="item-3">Item 3</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown 2</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="item-4"> <label for="item-4">Item 4</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="item-5"> <label for="item-5">Item 5</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="item-6"> <label for="item-6">Item 6</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Having a list of dropdowns I'd like to close other dropdown list if one is clicked and close itself if its already open. First part is working however button isn't closing the currently open dropdown list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target instead your parent `.dropdown` wrappers, toggle a class like `is-active`, style in CSS accordingly.

- Use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and the respective `.toggle()` and `.remove()` prototype methods:

```js
const elsDD = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown')

elsDD.forEach(elDD => {
  elDD.querySelector(".dropdown-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    elsDD.forEach(el => {
      el.classList[el === elDD ? "toggle" : "remove"]("is-active");
    });
  }); 
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 50px;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-list {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown.is-active .dropdown-list {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown 1</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="1">Item 1</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="2">Item 2</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="3">Item 3</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown 2</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="c2" value="4"> Item 4</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="c2" value="5"> Item 5</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="c2" value="6"> Item 6</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

The above solution is pretty slick since you can style as *"active"* not only the `.dropdown` wrapper, but also any child element by just descending from the parent: `.dropdown.is-active .dropdown-btn { background: gold; }`. You get the point.